# React.Intl substring from <FormattedMessage>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, react-intl

I'm working on my first project with i18n and I've run into this issue. My client wants a navigation bar with texts expanding depending on the currently viewed section. Something like this:

[image: navigation bar]

[image: navigation bar]

So for each label I'm using FormattedMessages like this:

```
<FormattedMessage id="navigation.what"/>
<FormattedMessage id="navigation.how"/>
```

I get all the strings from .json file.

Now I'm thinking - do you know if there's **any way to use .substring  on the FormattedMessage?**

Also does this approach make any sense or should I just use different strings for expanded and shortened label in .json and be done with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<FormattedMessage id="navigation.what"/>` component will always returns a span. For getting string from `react-intl`, you should be using `formatMessage()` function. You can use it like the below:

Inject Intl using `injectIntl` higher order component:

```
import { injectIntl } from 'react-intl';

@injectIntl
class YourComponent extends Component {
...
render () {
...
  const {formatMessage} = this.props.intl;
...
  <span>{formatMessage(navigation.how).substring()}</span>
```

Go through this function for more details:
[formatMessage()](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/blob/f82383e02cb0d38dfd28649dc2442a2ea2796a44/src/format.js#L172)

[Usage example](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/blob/b82a899a59c762fcc590e1fa824b87da6ad409d9/examples/translations/src/client/components/locales-menu.js)